# Unrecognized option "driver" under "sylius_money"

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have installed SyliusCartBundle following the docs and when I run "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force" I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
Unrecognized option "driver" under "sylius_money"
```

My config.yml looks like in here http://sylius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusCartBundle/installation.html

```
#\app\config\config.yml   
sylius_cart:
    resolver: app.cart_item_resolver # The id of our newly created service.
    classes: ~ # This key can be empty but it must be present in the configuration.

sylius_order:
    driver: doctrine/orm 

sylius_money:
    driver: doctrine/orm
```

Comment: Doing a search in google, I've seen this problem come up with other Bundles from Sylius, it may be a bug (it usually is according to what I read), you should report it on github.

Comment: I have the same error while installing the Bundle please if find out the solution post it thx !

Comment: @Haithem Rihane I gave up couple days ago, but i hear rumor that update PHP could be helpful.

Comment: @sruj its realy annoying in github [here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/2396#issuecomment-72890475) i found that it's issue of documentation and the bundle don't have such option

Comment: @AdamElsodaney congrats ur PR is merged , i hope this bundle will be stabe in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've [submitted a PR](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Docs/pull/261) to update the docs for the Sylius CartBundle.

The configuration should be at its most simplistic:

```
sylius_money: ~
```

This equates to the default options, which are:

```
sylius_money:
    currency: EUR
    locale: en
```

However in Symfony, I'd recommend this setting:

```
sylius_money:
    locale: %locale%
```

Where `%locale%` is the value taking from `app/config/parameters.yml`.